# Calculate lines of the Inverse of Autocorrelation Matrix

Tags: autocorrelation, classification

I need to calculate the inverse of a autocorrelation matrix

$$\mathbf R_{xx} = E\left\{\mathbf x \mathbf x^T\right\}$$

Where the samples $\mathbf x$ are $266000\times 1$ vectors, which means I'll have a $266000\times 266000$ matrix and need to invert it. But I only need the first 729 lines. The problem is, I have to find a classifier $\mathbf h$, where
$$\mathbf h = \mathbf R_{xx}^{-1}\mathbf u$$

where $\mathbf R_{xx}$ is the autocorrelation matrix and $\mathbf u$ is a $266000\times 1$ vector.

I have $\mathbf u$ and I can calculate $\mathbf R_{xx}$, but I can't save it on memory (it's a matrix larger than 400GB and I only have 380GB available). I'm only interested in the first 729 lines of $\mathbf h$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a rank one Cholesky update approach.

Comment: Wow! Stan!  Welcome!  Would you mind expanding on that a bit? You can use LaTeX-style formulae here. The system is flagging this as "Low Quality" because it's a little... terse. :-)

Comment: Well, I gave it a search and actually found a "solution", not using Cholesky but Schur Complement (that I came across searching by Cholesky).

Answer (score 0):

To follow on Stan's comment. The intuition is that inverse of a (Hermitian) matrix can be computed via Cholesky decomposition but that you update that decomposition as you compute more lines of the inverse. I don't have an implementation handy but there is some info on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Updating_the_decomposition)

Another related idea along the lines of dimensionality reduction, if you are doing an $$ Ax = b $$ type least-square optimization (which it appears you are), is to use SVD and the [pseudoinverse](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/corpcor/html/pseudoinverse.html). [Another link](http://gsite.univ-provence.fr/gsite/Local/lpc/dir/courrieu/articles/Courrieu05b.pdf).

From http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jepson/csc420/notes/introSVD.pdf
[image]